# Can I prevent babel-preset-es2015 from encode unicode characters in template literals?

Tags: javascript, unicode, ecmascript-6, babeljs, string-literals

For example, `` `你好嗎` `` will be convert to `'\u4F60\u597D\u55CE';`

But I expect it to be `'你好嗎'`, can I prevent from doing this?

[example on babel repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=AaA3lL6ahzqsBQDk4VkA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=)

Comment: @connexo yes they can; those fit in UTF-16. (By "fit" I mean that they don't require two-character escapes for representation.)

Comment: You are correct, nonetheless I assume this is the reason Babel chose a fail-safe way to transpile those characters. https://leanpub.com/understandinges6/read/#leanpub-auto-strings-and-regular-expressions

Comment: Agreed, yes I'm sure it's just caution. I'm not sure why it'd make a difference; the `\u` versions will work just fine.

Comment: I guess it's about output readability and code size. SInce it's only template literal that is transformed but not regular '你好嗎' string, this transform doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Why do you think it matters?

Comment: @Bergi “你好吗” takes 9 bytes (3 for each Chinese character encoded in UTF-8), while '\uxxxx...' takes 18 bytes (6 for each Chinese character).

Comment: BTW, have you found a way to prevent this transformation?